# Remote Debugging with Eclipse and tomcat

Tags: remote-debugging

I have an application deployed on linux server with some ip say 11.22.33.44

Server Details

Java version - "1.6.0_14"

IP - 11.22.33.44

when i start the server i am getting the following o/p on server console
'-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8004'

This means i had set all the required information for starting the server in debug mode

Client side Setting (Other windows 7 machine)

For connection properties on eclipse the details are as follows
Host : 11.22.33.44 (As above)
Port : 8004         (As above)

I guess every thing is done correctly but still getting the

**Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.Connection timed out: connect**

error

From my client machine where eclipse is running i am able to ping the server machine i.e. 11.22.33.44

Answer (score 2):

sounds like a firewall issue.
Can you telnet from the command line on the given machine / port? 
Try this:

```
telnet 11.22.33.44 8004
```

if this fails then it means your port is not open -- either your JVM ignored the parameters and is not listening on that port or there is a firewall blocking your access.
In order to identify which one it is, you can log onto the machine running tomcat and

```
telnet localhost 8004
```

if this succeeds it means your jvm is accepting remote debug connections on that port and therefore the problem is a firewall in your network, if it fails it means you haven't started the JVM with the correct remote debug params.

Comment: when i am doing  lsof -i on my linux machine then **java    16295 cdc-ops    5u  IPv4 13057055       TCP *:8004 (LISTEN)** is showing up that means the server is running on debug port 8004

Comment: Pardon? :O Have you missed something in your last comment?

Comment: does the above statement means the server is accepting the connection at port 8004

Comment: yes that should mean that the java process with pid 16295 is listening on port 8004 on **ALL** addresses defined for that host (so localhost as well as the external interface). this doesn't mean that there is no firewall running (even on the same host) to block access to that port -- it simply means if a packet reaches that host on port 8004 (bypassing any firewalls) it will be shipped to your java process.

Comment: thanks.... As per your comments when i am firing the command i.e tlenet 11.22.33.44 on my linux machine it is showing **telnet 11.22.33.44 8004
Trying 11.22.33.44...
Connected to 11.22.33.44.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
ape.online.ea.com{cdc-ops}61:**

Does this means the server is not accepting the communication on that port

Comment: I'm guessing you ran that command on your server (the one running tomcat which you are trying to connect to from your windows machine) right? The line "Connected to 11.22.33.44" means that you have actually connected to that port -- so your Tomcat **IS** listening on that port! (The fact that the connection was closed shortly after simply means you didn't follow the protocol expected and/or didn't send anything in a timely fashion so don't worry about that.) Altogether, what this means is that your server is configured correctly and ready for remote debugging.

Comment: Thanks........That means there is no issue with the server. Now i need to check with my local windows machine. This is a windows 7 as mention above. At present telnet is not working on this may be i will be back once i will resolve this with admin people

Comment: One more question sir..... If i am able to ping that machine does it means that there is no firewall between my local machine and server machine

Comment: no, ping works at ICMP level not at TCP level so ping just ensures you that there is a route to your machine. The only way to test connectivity on a port is telnet'ing into that port. On windows, you will need to go into control panel/Programs and features (or similar)/windows components and add the telnet client to be able to use it in the command line.

Comment: you're welcome! And feel free to rate my answers as well by the way ;)

Answer (score 0):

After checking the following there is another source of error: Connection Type. So for others having the same issue, shall follow this problem resolution path:

1. Ping the host that hosts your application (server). If not successful, check that you have one leg of your NIC in the same network as your target host - if working with IPs instead of hosts.
2. telnet your host. e.g. telnet 192.168.0.2 8889 . If you can connect shortly, then that is fine. Seeing connection refused message is no success. "Connection closed by foreign host" is fine though.
3. Now open Eclipse and create a Remote Debugging Configuration. Enter the same host and port that you previously telneted. Select Connection Type "**Standard (Socket Attach)**". **Caution**, if you see two of this same instance in the selection box, try both. Sometime one of these does NOT work.

This should do it. If not, drop a message and I help out.